# Как создавать окна draggable (jQuery) количество и размеры (x, y) должны читаться из бд

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть таблица в БД, где есть id/ширина/высота/X/Y. Разобрался немного с плагином draggable, но неясно как создавать эти окна исходя из значей в БД. Получается, что мне как-то значения из запроса нужно связывать с функцией вызова окон? Не совсем понимаю. Может быть есть какие-либо примеры?

Comment: Примеры конечно есть. В сети миллиарды примеров работы ajax + PHP + mysql ......... да и тут сотни вопросов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bajax%5D+mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разместите ваш элемент изначально в нужном месте с помощью абсолютного позиционирования, подставив нужные координаты при генерации html:

```
<div ... style="position:absolute; top:40px; left:120px; width:100px; height:50px">...</div>
```

Никаких дополнительных действий в скрипте не требуется:

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".draggble" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```css
.draggble{
border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggble" style="position:absolute; top:40px; left:120px; width:100px; height:50px">Test</div>
```

Comment: Это я усвоил, но требуется как-то брать и присваивать значения из базы - вот это мне непонятно, именно по данному поводу задал вопрос. Но всё равно спасибо.

Comment: Всё, разобрался с данными из БД, сразу почему-то не догадался. Спасибо.